# Can a forms modality be suspended during pascalscript debugging?

Tags: delphi, pascalscript

Suppose you include a pascal scripting IDE in your application and a script is created that generates a modal form with a button on it and in the button onclick event, you place a debugger breakpoint.

The result, when that button is pressed, will be a deadlocked program that only task manager can kill.

Obviously you don't want to do that, but it would be difficult to control what end users do.

So I was wondering if there was any way to suspend connected modal forms when the pascalscript debugger breakpoint was hit.?

Comment: I think the solution for any debugging scenario is to not run the debugger in the same thread as the one executing the script. Running a multithreaded UI in Delphi isn't trivial, but it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot suspend window modality. It's not a flag.

Modal window runs its own message pump. Which is many levels up in a call stack from the event handler. You cannot change call stack.